# Prove that exists $A\subset \mathbb R^2$, with $y$-projection dense in $\mathbb R$ and single $x$-projection.

Tags: real-analysis

For any $R\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, let

- $H(R,y) :=\big\{ x \mid (x,y)\in R\big\}.$
- $V(R,x) :=\big\{ y \mid (x,y)\in R\big\}.$

I need a help for proving that exists $A\subset \mathbb R^2$, such that $H(A,y)$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ for all $y\in \mathbb R$, and for every $x\in\mathbb R$, witch $V(A,x)$ has at maximun one element.

I've tryed considering the set ${\cal F}:=\big\{]a,b[\times\{y\} \,\big| \,a<b \hspace{5px}\text{and }a,b,y\in\mathbb R\big\}$, or at least some subset of $\cal F$, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has cardinality $\mathrm{Card}(\mathbb{R})$. Let $(e_y)_{y \in \mathrm{R}}$ be a basis.

Then $A=\{ (q+e_y,y) \vert q \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ has the property you are looking for.

Comment: Correct. If $B$ is a Hamel (vector-space) basis, with cardinal $|B|$, for a vector space $V$ over the field $\Bbb Q$ then,  since $|\Bbb Q|=\aleph_0,$ we have $|V|=|B|\cdot  \aleph_0.$ In particular, when $V=\Bbb R $ we have $\aleph_0<|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}=|B|\cdot \aleph_0,$ implying $|B|=|\Bbb R|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = \Bbb{R} / \Bbb{Q} = \{[r]: r \in \Bbb{R} \}$ with $[r]=[s]$ iff $r-s \in \Bbb{Q}$.

Then the cardinality of $S$ is that of $\Bbb{R}$.

Hence, there exists a bijection $g: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow S$.

And there exists a choice function $h: S \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that $h([r])$ is one of $\{r+q:q\in\Bbb{Q}\}$.

Let $f:\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be $h \circ g$.

Let $A_r = \{(f(r)+q,r): q \in \Bbb{Q} \}$ for all $r \in \Bbb{R}$.

And let $A = \cup_{r \in \Bbb{R}} A_r$.

Then $A$ is the desired set.